# Module with multiple providers

Tags: module, terraform

I have a question regarding the following.

I am using terraform with fortios provider

tree:

[image]

these are my providers in the root-prod:

```
provider "fortios" {
  hostname = "xxxxx"
  token    = "xxxxx"
  insecure = "true"
  vdom     = "PROD"
}

provider "fortios" {
  hostname = "xxxx"
  token    = "xxxx"
  insecure = "true"
  vdom     = "OPS"
  alias    = "isops"
}
```

I h got my root-module-prod:

```
module "AWS_xxx"{
  source = "../modules"
  name = "AWS_PROD"
  prefix_lists = local.aws_prod
  providers = { 
    fortios.dc1 = fortios
    fortios.dc2 = fortios.isops 
  } 
}
```

provider & resource within-child-modules:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    fortios = {
      source  = "fortinetdev/fortios"
      version = "1.13.1"
      configuration_aliases = [ fortios.dc1, fortios.dc2 ]
    }
  }
}

resource "fortios_router_prefixlist" "prefix_lists" {
  name   = var.name
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.prefix_lists
    content { 
      id     = rule.value["id"]
      action = rule.value["action"]
      prefix = rule.value["prefix"]
      ge     = rule.value["ge"]
      le     = rule.value["le"]
    }
  }
}
```

my goal is for the above module to create two instances of the resource, one in each of the declared providers.

My issue is that while the resource is created in the first provider PROD it doesn't crated in OPS.

Do you have any clue on this..?

Comment: did you ever find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Not really did not work through Terraform-multi-providers.
In our case, I found a way through Jenkins Parallelism.
We launch in parallel multiple envs with the credentials saved encrypted in Jenkins server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).